# How do I recognize the extension that has taken over markdown editing

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I suddenly find that my markdown files are being opened by a wysiwyg editor with chinese menus. No language is detected and searching through my extensions gave no hint. How do I figure out which extension is active?
[image: Screen with strange extension]

Comment: Could you list the installed extensions?

Comment: The active ones are: "Live server", "Javascript debugger", "Github copilot", "Ofiice viewer", lean, lean4, gitlens, "Markdown language features", "git history", git, "code spell check", vscode-icons, bracket-pair-colorizer, github-authentication, emmet, "Microsoft account", "Material theme icon", "extension authoring", "code spell checker", "ansi colors", "reveal", "word counter", "multiple clipboards"

Comment: Try using the `Start Extension Bisect` command from the Command Palette - it will help narrow down which is the offending extension.

Comment: TIL, @Mark. Very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there is a command called "Developer: Show Running Extensions" that you can activate from the command palette.

In this case, I see a weird spelling in that screenshot: "Vditor".

[Searching for that word](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=%22vditor%22&ia=web) finds a few pages, including [one](https://www.libhunt.com/compare-vditor-vs-vscode-markdown-editor) whose title is "vditor VS vscode-markdown-editor". From that page, I found [`Vanessa219/vditor`](https://github.com/Vanessa219/vditor).

That project claims to be

> An In-browser Markdown editor, support WYSIWYG (Rich Text), Instant Rendering (Typora-like) and Split View modes

but not a Visual Studio Code plugin.

However, the extension [vscode all markdown](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TobiasTao.vscode-md) says it is "powered by" Vditor. I suspect you'll find that's the plugin to disable.

There is also something called [vscode-office](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-office). It uses Vditor for Markdown out of the box, but this can be disabled:

> It change markdown editor as vditor, it's WYSIWYG editor for markdown...
>
> if you want using vscode editor, insert below json to vscode config.
>
> ```
> "workbench.editorAssociations": [{
>   "viewType": "default",
>   "filenamePattern": "*.md"
> }]
> ```

Comment: Try disabling all of your extensions and then enabling them one at a time. Does this affect files in arbitrary projects or just one project? Have you installed anything from anywhere except the official extension repository?

Comment: Is "office viewer" [this thing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-office)? It also says it uses Vditor, but I don't see it listed in [the official marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode) so I'm not sure how you'd have installed it.

Comment: Actually, [it is in the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-office) under the name "office viewer". That's your problem. See my updated answer for how to restore the default Markdown behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was indeed the "office viewer" that was causing the problem. I have uninstalled it and everything is fine.